# Is using an old Android phone for 2-factor authentication safe?

Tags: authentication, mobile, android

I apologize in advance if this is the wrong place to ask this, I didn't know a better place to start.

I have a rooted HTC Hero (CDMA) that is no longer receiving service and is just kind of...sitting there. Would it be safe to use it as just a device for accessing Google Authenticator? If not, please explain why not. I understand the risks of potentially losing it/not having it with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly safe if it's off the network. Something like that is an excellent use for an old device that's completely off the network -- as long as it stays in time sync.

Comment: How would I make sure it stays synced? Can it do this over wifi?

Comment: Yes, and if it doesn't seem to be working, there are apps that can do that (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/inaccurate-time-how-to-fix-it?rq=1).